# Connect to Chrome Remote Debugger using ClientWebSocket

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I’m trying to connect to Chrome using it’s [remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol) with [WebSocket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.aspx) introduced in .NET Framework 4.5.

This is my sample code and I’m getting an error message saying "unable to connect to server".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Program p = new Program();
 p.MyMethod();
 Console.ReadLine();
}

public async void MyMethod()
{
 var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
 var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["debug_url"], UriKind.Absolute);
 await ws.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);

 Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="debug_url" value="ws://127.0.0.1:9220/devtools/page/18DA69D1-70E0-428F-985E-9E600B07311E" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

What is the correct way to connect to chrome with WebSocket Class ?

Platform : Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work this way. You have to ask for the list of tabs via

```
http ://127.0.0.1:9220/json/list
```

parse the answer which has tab ids and the urls, and use these ids for connecting via web socket. Chrome generates the ids on the fly. So the next time they will be different.

Comment: Yes, First I opened a tab and got the ID. Then set the value in config file and tested the application. I always change the ID accordingly. This is working with WebSocket4Net (https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/) and I want to try with WebSocket Class in .NET Framework 4.5 .